# Using INDEX, MATCH and COUNTIFS to filter and match data in Excel. Formula incorrect?

Tags: excel, indexing, match, countif

I am trying to use `INDEX`, `MATCH` and `COUNTIFS` in excel to filter for relevant data within 2 spreadsheets. However, the formula below only returns the first value of per the matched criteria and replicates this value throughout the identified rows:

```
IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,$A43,J:J,G$3),INDEX(L:L,MATCH(G$3,J:J,0))),"")
```

*Please see a sample of the criteria i am trying to match below. If the IDs and Names in table 1 and 2 are matched, display the % Allocated in Table 2. The problem i'm having is that the formula only matches Bill at 10% and displays 10% for every other matched name.

```
    Table 1:            

    ID     Name    Project % Allocated
    4121    Bill    30100   10%
    4122    Murray  30200   30%
    4123    Harmon  30300   50%
    4132    John    30408   40%


    Table 2:            

    ID     Name    Project % Allocated
    4121    Bill    30100   
    4122    Murray  30200   
    4131    Shauna  30407   
    4132    John    30408
```

Comment: I am afraid that this is how index match works. It looks for the *first* match and returns an index. There are more complex formulas available that will allow you to get a full list but they are a step up from regular index match and will require more information of your data.

Comment: Are you entering it as an array formula?

Comment: No i am not, please kindly see above for more detail on the data .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ID` is unique to both lists `vlookup` will work.

In Table2 % Allocated formula:

```
=vlookup(A2,Table1!A:D,4,0)
```

If unique combination is `ID` and `Name` as you state this array formula will work.

```
=INDEX(Table1!D:D,Match(A2&B2,Table!A:A&Table1!B:B,0))
```

Be sure to press **Ctrl** + **Shift** + **Enter** when exiting cell edit mode.

*assume that Table1 and Table2 are on two separate sheets (named accordingly) in column A:D*

Answer (score 0):

Make a reference to the row number using row () +1. This will make it so that the range it is looking for becomes smaller and smaller as it works its way down the list. This will make it a dynamic formula. Can you show a picture of what you are trying to do. Right now the idea isnt all that tangible.

Comment: Thanks, please see above for more detail on the data